# Why is my delete_last_element of a linked list deleting the first element?

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am writing a function that is supposed to delete the last element of a linked list

This is my definition for a node

```
struct Node {
  int key;
  Node* next;
  };
```

I have a node list 1 that runs the insert function 3 times for the values 1, 2, 3

The insert function looks like this

```
void insert( Node*& head, int key) {
  Node * curr = new Node;
  curr->key  = key;
  curr->next = head;

  head = curr;
}
```

Now my delete_last_element function looks like this

```
void delete_last_element( Node*& head )
{


    Node  *curr;    
    if (head == NULL)
        return;

    curr = head->next; 
    if (curr == NULL){
        delete head;
        head = NULL;
        return;
    }
    head = curr;

      while (curr->next != NULL) {
        head = curr;
        curr = curr->next;
      }

      delete head->next;
      head -> next = NULL;


}
```

Basically my idea is i would first see if the first element is null, if so then i do nothing since there is no last element. I then set curr to head->next to look at the next element in the list, if that is null I will delete head, since I know it is the last element and return.

Now that i know the first element is not the last element, I assign head to curr, or the second element. From here I enter the while loop and check if the next element (starting from the 3rd) is null, if it is I delete the current element, if not I move head to the next element and then check the next element after that.

Now my linked list originally starts as 3 2 1, but for whatever reason when I run the delete_last_element function it becomes 2 instead of 3 2.

Can anyone tell me what I might be doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: `delete_last_element` leaks the whole list. It deletes the last element, leaves `head` pointing to the next-to-last element (which now has become the last), and leaves all preceding nodes unreachable.

Comment: Hi igor, if I am understanding you correctly, I am not actualyl deleting the 3? I am only deleting the 1 and leaving the 3 unreachable? Is this correct?

Comment: Correct. The "3" node is leaked.

Comment: What would be the best way to fix this only changing my delete_last_element function then? I tried not using head and only moving curr but I get a double free or corruption error

Comment: Don't modify `head` (unless the list consists of a single element, and transitions to an empty list). Use another local variable to chase behind `curr`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you have two conditions to look out for in this example:

- The list is empty.
- There is only one element in the list.

If the list is empty then it is indicated by the `head` pointer pointing to `nullptr`. If there's no list then there's nothing to delete, so we can exit the function:

```
if (head == nullptr)
    return;
```

The reason checking if there is only one element in the list is useful is if we are keeping two pointers to traverse the list - one to the current element and one before the current element. The "previous" pointer will have to set its `next` pointer to `nullptr` after the current node is deleted. If there is no previous node (because there is only one element) then we can't use a previous pointer.

```
if (!head->next)
{
    delete head;
    head = nullptr;
    return;
}

node *prev = nullptr, // previous is nullptr
     *curr = head;    // start at head
```

Now we have to traverse the list to find the last element. You should not use `head` to traverse the list as `head` is needed to signify the beginning of the list, you can't have it pointing anywhere else, so we use `curr` instead.

```
while (curr->next)
{
    prev = curr;
    curr = curr->next;
}
```

Now that we have reached the end of the list we can delete `curr` and set the previous pointers `next` to `nullptr`:

```
delete curr;
prev->next = nullptr;
```

And that's it. Here's the full method:

```
void delete_last_element(node*& head)
{
    if (head == nullptr) // list is empty, nothing to do
        return;

     if (head->next == nullptr) // only one element in list
     {
         delete head;
         head = nullptr; // set back to nullptr
         return; // get outta here
     }

     node *prev = nullptr,
          *curr = head;

     while (curr->next)
     {
         prev = curr;
         curr = curr->next;
     }

     delete curr;
     prev->next = nullptr;
}
```

[Here is a demo showing its use](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e8e33f6374bee7a2).

---

Once you understand the above code you can figure out how to shorten it.

```
void delete_last_element(node*& head)
{
    node **curr = &head;
    while (curr[0] && curr[0]->next)
        curr = &curr[0]->next;

    delete *curr;
    *curr = nullptr;
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot for the reply. Just one question though, could you explaina  bit more about why we cannot use head? Why is head needed to indicate the start of the list?

Comment: Actually I think I know what you mean now, so basically if we move head, whenever other functions call this list they will now start from whatever head was moved to? So say we have a list 1>2>3>4>5, if head was originally 5 but after this function it was moved to 2, then the linked list essentially just becomes NULL>2?

Comment: @user3504410 `head` should always be pointing to the beginning of the list. Without it you won't know where the list begins. If we move `head` then we loose the previous links and there's no way to get them back (with a singly linked list implementation like yours). The only time you should move `head` is when you are changing the beginning of the list (like deletion/insertion).

Answer (score 0):

In your insert function you are always setting next to point to head:

```
curr->next = head;
```

and on top of that you are changing your head to the newest element,

```
head = curr;
```

which is the last item in the linked list. So you are actually, accidentally making the linked list backwards.

To draw it out this is what you are doing; the downwards arrow points at head, the side ways arrows point at next

insert 1:

```
|
v
1
```

insert 2: (you are creating a new node: 2, then you are making it's next be the previous head, which was 1, and then you are setting the current node, 2, as the new head)

```
     |
     v
1 <- 2
```

insert 3:

```
          | 
          v
1 <- 2 <- 3
```

Comment: I am not entirely sure what curr->next = head means, does this mean that whenever I call curr->next in any function it points to the value of whatever head was passed in as? The insert function shouldn't be changed as it was given, so insert(1), insert(2), insert(3) in that order should create a linked list that has 3 2 1

Comment: in a typical linked list implementation, you should get : 1->2->3 from insert 1 insert 2 insert 3, with head always being 1, in this case. If you want to do it the way you are, look at Igor's comment to see the problem.

Comment: I think that the reason I thought it was 3->2->1 is because the print function giving might be printing from right to left then. So if I wanted to start deleting from the left (1), im assuming my head/curr would initially be 3, then head->next (or is it curr-> next or do they work the same?) would point to 2, and then the next head->next would point to 1? And that is what I should be deleting?

Comment: @user3504410 - So your linked list is really a stack?  That's what it boils down to if `insert` puts things in the front.

Answer (score 0):

Recursion is useful here. A list is either:

> 1. empty
> 2. has exactly one element
> 3. has more than one element

We deal with each of those three cases as follows:

```
void delete_last_element( Node*& head ) {
    if(head == NULL) {
         // The list is empty, nothing to remove.
         // Just do nothing and return
         return;
    }
    else if (head->next == NULL) {
         // This list has exactly one element.
         // Remove it and return
         delete head; // free the memory
         head = NULL; // the single-element list is now an empty list
         return;
    }
    else {
        // We have a list with more than one element.
        // Let's be lazy
        delete_last_element(head->next);
        return;
    }
```

Each of the three cases is dealt with in turn. The last case ("a list that has more than one element") is dealt with simply by calling `delete_last_element(head->next);`. The idea is that deleting the last element from a 5-element list that starts at `head` is exactly the same as deleting a 4-element list that starts at `head->next`.